# When/where we use XMLRPC

Tags: php, xml-rpc

I heard that many of the blog sites are using this protocol. I want to know what is that and when/where we use this XMLRPC?

Any example with PHP would be appreciable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use an XML-RPC Server when you want to expose an XML-RPC interface (API) to your application.

You use an XML-RPC client to connect to an XML-RPC server.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC

For examples with PHP see [Zend_XmlRpc_Client](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.client.html) and [Zend_XmlRpc_Server](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.xmlrpc.server.html).

If you're familiar with MVC, think of it as another View/Controller for your Model. You expose functions within your application to the outside world via XML-RPC.

Answer (score 1):

XML-RPC is the predecessor of SOAP. SOAP evolved from XML-RPC. XML-RPC is ancient ([1998](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML-RPC)), and almost unused today.

Comment: Care to explain the reason for the downvote? Is this inaccurate?

Comment: Fact: XML-RPC predates SOAP. Subjective: It's ancient, and almost unused today.

Comment: @hobodave: ancient means it's over ten years old. Almost unused is quite objective - who's using it? Where's the tool support? XML-RPC became SOAP, then should have quietly died. "became SOAP" is objective. "then should have quietly died" is subjective. And that's why my answer didn't say "should have quietly died".

Comment: I use it. My company uses it. I know rather large enterprise projects that are using it.

Comment: @hobodave: Please add an answer saying why you still use it, and better still, why anyone should write a new application using it. You might also say why you prefer dinosaurs to birds.

Comment: My company uses it too.  I think it is inaccurate to say "hardly used".  It's got an advantage over SOAP in terms of being simple.  But lately I've been wondering what benefit it provides over plain XML.

Comment: @Tim Cooper: Please add an answer saying why you still use it, and better still, why anyone should write a new application using it. You might also say why you prefer dinosaurs to birds.